# Deleting a row using PHP but only works sometimes

Tags: php, html, database, rows

I'm having a problem with deleting a row from the database; the connection is absolutely fine, as I have tested it with other things and the variable `$first` contains the right ID to delete.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['production'])) {   
    $production = $_GET['production'];

    $arr = explode(".", $production, 2);
    $first = $arr[0];

    $filename = "Productions/$first.php";

    echo $first;

    if(file_exists($filename)==true){
        $str2 = "DELETE FROM production WHERE production_id = '$first'";
            if($mysqli->query($str2)==true){
                echo "Successfully deleted $first";
                unlink($filename);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by sometimes?

Comment: Have you considered adding error checking?

Comment: You should use post rather than get for deleting. Not that this will fix your problem, just prevent others.

Comment: It's strange when I had lots of entries in the database, some of them would delete using this, but others would do nothing. Basically I am allowing the user to select a row they'd like to delete using a form and <option></option> and assigning the action to the same page with passing the variable 'production' using _GET.

Comment: I have added lots of if statements and var_dump() but I just can't figure out why this is not working, everything seems to be correct.

Comment: Are you testing the same id over and over? Could be a browser caching issue if you are.

Comment: Just tested it with another browser, no luck :-(

Comment: I think it's a better idea to rephrase your question.

Comment: The DELETE is dependent on the IF (file_exists()). Have you checked that this is always true?

Comment: Yeah that if_exists() is correct.

Comment: Found the problem! It was a foreign key constraint, sorry guys.